# iOS Swift: best way to pass data to other VCs after query is completed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

**Context:** iOS App written in Swift 3 powered by Firebase 3.0

**Challenge:** On my app, the user's *currentScore* is stored on Firebase. This user can complete/un-complete tasks (that will increase/decrease its *currentScore*) from several ViewControllers.

**Overview of the App's architecture:**

> ProfileVC - where I fetch the currentUser's data from Firebase & display the currentScore.
>
> ⎿ ContainerView
>
> ```
>   ⎿ CollectionViewController - users can update their score from here
>
>      ⎿ DetailsVC - (when users tap on a collectionView cell) - again users can update their score from here.
> ```

[image]

**Question:** I need to pass the currentScore to the VCs where the score can be updated. I thought about using prepare(forSegue) in cascade but this doesn't work since it passes "nil" before the query on ProfileVC is finished.

I want to avoid having a global variable as I've been told it's bad practice.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Global variables are not bad practice if used correctly and sparingly. Apple covers their use in the developer docs. In your case, if the data is needed App-wide it may be appropriate. You mention prepareForSegue.. That's a good place to pass a variable and it's not clear why it would pass nil. Are you doing a Firebase query each time the view is changed? If so, that's adds a lot of unnecessary overhead. If it is needed, start the segue *after* Firebase has returned from the query, within the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiation, first embed a navigation controller to your first storyboard, and then give a **storyboardID** to the VC you are going to show.

```
 let feedVCScene = self.navigationController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerVC_ID") as! ViewController

 feedVCScene.scoreToChange = current_Score //  scoreToChange is your local variable in the class

                                           //  current_Score is the current score of the user.

 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(feedVCScene, animated: true)
```

**PS:-** The reason why instantiation is much healthier than a *modal segue storyboard transfer* , it nearly removes the memory leaks that you have while navigating to and fro, also avoid's stacking of the VC's.

Comment: Hey Dravidian, thanks for your answer. I've added a screenshot of my storyboard for this specific section. I've used a third party library to create a swipable page menu to filter  my collectionView. So basically once the User loads its profileScreen. Both the profile elements and the collectionView load at the same time which is why the segue fires too early (vs. my query). I'm not sure I've understood what you meant by instantiation. Is that still relevant with the additional details I added? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yup, its still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a function that will pull all data before you do anything else.

So in ViewDidLoad call...

```
pullFirebaseDataASYNC()
```

Function will look like below...

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (_ success: Bool) -> Void

func pullFirebaseDataASYNC() {

    self.pullFirebaseDataFunction() { (success) -> Void in
        if success {

            // Perform all other functions and carry on as normal...
```

Firebase function may look like...

```
    func pullFirebaseDataFunction(completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) {

    let refUserData = DBProvider.instance.userDataRef
    refUserData.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            self.userCurrentScore = dictionary["UserScore"] as! Int
            completionHandler(true)
        }
    })
}
```

Then when you segue the information across...
In ProfileVC
Create 2 properties

```
var containerVC: ContainerVC!
var userCurrentScore = Int()
```

Include the below function in ProfileVC...

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ProfileToContainerSegue" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! ContainerVC
        containerVC = destination

        containerVC.userCurrentScore = userCurrentScore
      }
    }
```

In ContainerVC create a property

```
    var userCurrentScore = Int()
```

Ways to improve could be an error message to make sure all the information is pulled from Firebase before the user can continue...
Then the information can be segued across the same way as above.